# error: https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch: key 1 import failed

Tags: elasticsearch, magento

openjdk version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.16.0.8-1.el9_0) (build 11.0.16+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.16.0.8-1.el9_0) (build 11.0.16+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

sudo rpm --import https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch

error: https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch: key 1 import failed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:SHA1
```

and

```
sudo rpm --import https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
```

Comment: It's actually weakening the whole system policy by allowing SHA1.